# Error with running ProcDump

Tags: c#, debugging, procdump

There is a ProcDump tutorial here: http://drdobbs.com/blogs/parallel/229300328

I have an application that crashes, so I want to see if ProcDump can help.
The application is in `C:\Program Files\MyCompanyName\thebadapp.exe` so I copied ProdCump.exe to C:\ and opened it like this:

```
C:\procdump -e C:\Program Files\MyCompanyName\thebadapp.exe
```

...but Prodcump is returning:

> The Directory C:\Files\MyCompanyName\ does not exist

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs to be:

```
C:\>procdump -e thebadapp.exe BadApp.dmp
```

You don't need to provide the path to the EXE, just the name.  ProcDump will find it in the list of running processes by name.  If you want to path out the location for your dump file you can:

```
C:\>procdump -e thebadapp.exe C:\Program Files\MyCompanyName\BadApp.dmp
```